# Por que mi vista content no se muestra en mi vista principal?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

**Esta es mi vista principal "main" ubicada en la carpeta layouts**

```
<body>

    <div>
        @yield("content")
        
    </div>
    
</body>
```

**Esta es mi vista "content" que extiende de la vista principal**

```
@extends("layouts.main")

    @section("content")
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
      
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
     @endsection
```

[image: Ubicación de las vistas]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No aparece el contenido de la tabla en mi vista principal y laravel no me manda ningún error**

Comment: listo, retorne la vista directamente en la ruta

Comment: ok muchas gracias esa parte era la que no entendia, te lo agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Típicamente, en el layout es donde están la etiquetas `<head>` y `<body>`, y agregas los `@yield` que rellenarán las plantillas blade que extienden de ella. Más info en la doc [Layouts Using Template Inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance).

Por ejemplo si tienes un layout así, donde dejas un yield para el título y otro para el contenido:

```
<!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Puedes extender todas las plantillas que quieras de esa layout, y asignar el "relleno" para cada yield:

```
<!-- resources/views/home.blade.php -->
 
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('title', 'Home Page')
 
@section('content')
    <p>Este es el contenido de Home Page.</p>
@endsection
```

---

```
<!-- resources/views/about.blade.php -->
 
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('title', 'About Page')
 
@section('content')
    <p>Este es el contenido de About Page.</p>
@endsection
```

Y en la ruta (o controlador), devuelves las vistas "hijas":

```
Route::view('/', 'home');
Route::view('/about', 'about');
```

Ten en cuenta que la vista "padre" o layout, no sabe nada de las otras vistas que extienden de ella, y son la vista "hijas" las que saben de quién heredan.